# When asynctask in activity finishes how to reload ui in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask

My activity loads a fragment and starts an AsyncTask.

```
 class GetParkingAreasAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        return mRepository.getParkingAreas(mContext.getActiveUser());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
        for (int i=0; i<mContext.getActiveUser().getParkingAreas().size(); i++){
            Log.i(TAG_areas, "parking area " + i +": " + mContext.getActiveUser().getParkingAreas().get(i).getName());
        }
    }
}
```

This Asynctask in the Activity loads some data (I store in the context). When it finishes how can I reload the UI in fragment to show the data loaded (in the parent Activity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onPostExecute already runs in the UIThread, so you just need your fragment to call your Activity. The way I usually do this is by defining an interface for the fragment.
Like this:

```
public interface YourFragmentListener {
    void onParksLoaded(List<String> names)
}
```

Then on your Activity:

```
public class YourActivity implements YourFragmentListener {

    @Override
    void onParksLoaded(List<String names) {
        // Do something with the names
        yourField.setText(names.get(0))
    }

}
```

Finally in your fragment you can use it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
    ((YourFragmentListener) getActivity()).onParksLoaded(value)
}
```

Of course you can change the types to better fit your use case. Just beware of the cast, if you use this fragment in an activity that does not implements YourFragmentListener it will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

when you created the fragment you have an instance of him
so what you can do is onPostExecute to call the method on your fragment

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
yourFragment.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because i can't call a non-static method from onPostExecute (getView() and getContext() are both non-static methods). and i Have another task in that method that can't be loaded.

Comment: why not?
the async task located in your class?

Comment: the second asynctask is located in the fragment, to load an image from an url on an ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Define your desired method in the fragment to update UI, when async job is done, search for fragment in the parent activity and call the method on fragment instance

**MyFragment**:

```
public void refreshUI(String data) {
   //Do something with data you receive     
}
```

**ParentActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
    //or you can find it with tag if have any
    MyFragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if(frag != null) frag.refreshUI(value);
}
```